# ggplot2 not transparent though alpha is used

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two different data frames which I would like to overlay in a ggplot2:

```
plot3<- ggplot(fit3f, aes(x=exp(exp(.fitted)), y=.resid)) + 
  ggtitle("data points: 3") +
  xlab("Amplification") + ylab("res. pear.") +
  geom_point(colour="dodgerblue4") +
  # ylim(c(0,1)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=150, linetype="dashed", colour="orange", size=2) + 
  geom_point(data=fit3f_not_irr, aes(exp(exp(.fitted)), y=.resid, alpha = 0.05, colour="firebrick4"), show.legend  = FALSE)
```

but however, it is not transparent. Why is that?

[image: Plot]

Comment: The red points look transparent to me, there's just enough of them clustered together to block the view of that line. Switch the order of the geoms if you want the line on top.

Comment: That's true, figured that out, too by coincidence :)
But when I switch than it's the same around :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alpha = 0.05` slipped into your `aes(...)`-function call. Try this:

```
geom_point(data=fit3f_not_irr, aes(exp(exp(.fitted)), 
                               y=.resid, 
                               colour="firebrick4"),
       alpha = 0.05, 
       show.legend  = FALSE)
```